# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS lagging when connected with Sony WHX1000MX4

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, headphones, sony

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on my ThinkPad T470. When my Sony WHX1000MX4 Bluetooth headphones are connected to it, the whole system starts lagging and appears unstable.

I also use a Logitech MX Master 3S in Bluetooth mode, which runs fine.

Has anyone else run into this problem and found a solution?